# How does LWJGL store it's matrix3f data?

Tags: java, matrix, lwjgl

Can someone tell me what order LWJGL stores it's materix3f data?
http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix3f.html

I want to recreate the middle matrix (R.y) in this image:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/5/1/4/5148f88bf9e6811e35615c08d2839793.png

So, like would that -sin(angle) be in m.02, or m.20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas the storage order may differ when stored as a simple 1D-array, you can always be sure of the order when seeing double-indexed members, like `m02`. In these, the first number is the row and the second is the column.

This is the mathematical convention and is used by any matrix library I know. You can safely assume LWJGL to behave the same. If it really doesn't, write them a hate mail for doing such mathematically inconsistent rubbish.

So `-sin` goes into `m20`.